# How can I setup MongoDB with GoDaddy Shared Hosting?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, godaddy, mongodb

I would like to setup MongoDB with GoDaddy Shared Hosting (Linux). I have already enable SSH access. I can upload, extract, and run MongoDB succesfully outside of the doc root.

But, how do I ensure that MongoDB is always running and ready to accept transactions? How can I access it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible sorry, you might have been misled by the ability to SSH into your hosting provider.

Your best bet is to use a cheap dedicated server from someone like AWS or Rackspace Cloud or use a [MongoDB hosting service](https://mongohq.com/home)

Comment: does the same restriction apply to Win shared hosting? thanx.